# Neo4j taking forever to load

Tags: performance, neo4j, load, bigdata

I'm using Neo4j 3.2.1 on linux machine of 16G RAM .
I'm tryng to load a graph from a csv file of 11M row, the max number of node is for about 150K node.
It is taking forever to load, I have tried to increase the heap size , using periodic commit  from 10000 to 100000 but still nothing is changing it is hanging for about 2 hours now. 
I looked up the internet and found that it should not be taking that much time 
here is the configuration file

```
#*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#
# For more details and a complete list of settings, please see
# https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/
#*****************************************************************

# The name of the database to mount
#dbms.active_database=graph.db

# Paths of directories in the installation.
#dbms.directories.data=data
#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
#dbms.directories.certificates=certificates
#dbms.directories.logs=logs
#dbms.directories.lib=lib
#dbms.directories.run=run

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the
# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import

# Whether requests to Neo4j are authenticated.
# To disable authentication, uncomment this line
#dbms.security.auth_enabled=false

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
dbms.allow_format_migration=true

# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size.
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=15400m

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=14g

#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=

#*****************************************************************
# Logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# To enable HTTP logging, uncomment this line
#dbms.logs.http.enabled=true

# Number of HTTP logs to keep.
#dbms.logs.http.rotation.keep_number=5

# Size of each HTTP log that is kept.
#dbms.logs.http.rotation.size=20m

# To enable GC Logging, uncomment this line
#dbms.logs.gc.enabled=true

# GC Logging Options
# see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/819-0084-10/pt_tuningjava.html#wp57013 for more information.
#dbms.logs.gc.options=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

# Number of GC logs to keep.
#dbms.logs.gc.rotation.keep_number=5

# Size of each GC log that is kept.
#dbms.logs.gc.rotation.size=20m

# Size threshold for rotation of the debug log. If set to zero then no rotation will occur. Accepts a binary suffix "k",
# "m" or "g".
#dbms.logs.debug.rotation.size=20m

# Maximum number of history files for the internal log.
#dbms.logs.debug.rotation.keep_number=7

#*****************************************************************
# Miscellaneous configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher.default_language_version=3.0

# Determines if Cypher will allow using file URLs when loading data using
# `LOAD CSV`. Setting this value to `false` will cause Neo4j to fail `LOAD CSV`
# clauses that load data from the file system.
#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

# Retention policy for transaction logs needed to perform recovery and backups.
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days

# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
#dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
#dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
#dbms.shell.port=1337

# Only allow read operations from this Neo4j instance. This mode still requires
# write access to the directory for lock purposes.
#dbms.read_only=false

# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-server-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged

#********************************************************************
# JVM Parameters
#********************************************************************

# G1GC generally strikes a good balance between throughput and tail
# latency, without too much tuning.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC

# Have common exceptions keep producing stack traces, so they can be
# debugged regardless of how often logs are rotated.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

# Make sure that `initmemory` is not only allocated, but committed to
# the process, before starting the database. This reduces memory
# fragmentation, increasing the effectiveness of transparent huge
# pages. It also reduces the possibility of seeing performance drop
# due to heap-growing GC events, where a decrease in available page
# cache leads to an increase in mean IO response time.
# Try reducing the heap memory, if this flag degrades performance.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

# Trust that non-static final fields are really final.
# This allows more optimizations and improves overall performance.
# NOTE: Disable this if you use embedded mode, or have extensions or dependencies that may use reflection or
# serialization to change the value of final fields!
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields

# Disable explicit garbage collection, which is occasionally invoked by the JDK itself.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

# Remote JMX monitoring, uncomment and adjust the following lines as needed. Absolute paths to jmx.access and
# jmx.password files are required.
# Also make sure to update the jmx.access and jmx.password files with appropriate permission roles and passwords,
# the shipped configuration contains only a read only role called 'monitor' with password 'Neo4j'.
# For more details, see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
# On Unix based systems the jmx.password file needs to be owned by the user that will run the server,
# and have permissions set to 0600.
# For details on setting these file permissions on Windows see:
#     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3637
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/absolute/path/to/conf/jmx.password
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/absolute/path/to/conf/jmx.access

# Some systems cannot discover host name automatically, and need this line configured:
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$THE_NEO4J_SERVER_HOSTNAME

# Expand Diffie Hellman (DH) key size from default 1024 to 2048 for DH-RSA cipher suites used in server TLS handshakes.
# This is to protect the server from any potential passive eavesdropping.
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j

#********************************************************************
# Other Neo4j system properties
#********************************************************************
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=tarball
```

After a long time loading I have this error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000072c000000, 497025024, 0) failed; error='Ne peut allouer de l                        a mémoire' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 497025024 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

How can I solve this?

**Query**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.NodeID IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT  100000

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv'
AS line

MERGE (n1:Node {NodeID: line.p1})
MERGE (n2:Node {NodeID: line.p2})
MERGE (n1)-[:ACTING_WITH_L {Score: TOFLOAT(line.score)}]->(n2);
```

Comment: Can you provide your indexes/constraints, and your LOAD CSV query?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I have added the query to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran an EXPLAIN of your query, I noticed an EAGER operation in there. When EAGER is a part of the plan when using LOAD CSV, it falls back to a means of processing where it does not use PERIODIC COMMIT, and you run into memory issues.

Here's a [blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) about this, including the solution: ensure nodes are merged into the graph as a separate operation, and when you are sure the nodes are loaded, process the relationships separately MATCHing to nodes instead of using MERGE.

Instead of the `MERGE ... MERGE ... MERGE` pattern to merge in both nodes, then the relationship, use `MATCH ... MATCH ... MERGE`. Also, if you're sure none of the relationships exist in the graph already, you may want to use CREATE instead of MERGE on the relationship to speed it up.

Comment: when I had this issue, I did several LOAD CSV. Worked well too.
Try LOAD MERGE , LOAD MERGE and MATCH MATCH CREATE

Comment: @JeromeB  you say I should do the merge of each side of the node and the create  a relation ?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Does the number of periodic commit affect the usage of the memory ?  because matching the relationships is loading for about an hour now

Comment: @Muna arr Do 3 LOAD CSV. CREATE instead of MERGE when possible. See InverseFalcon answer for  the why